# Digital Logic - truth tables

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, truthtable

I am trying to solve these problems with truth tables using the formulas below. I am having a problem with the NOT to NAND

I think i got the first 2 problems correct using: AND is equivalent to NOR, AND is  equivalent to NAND

The equations for AND, OR and NOT using the NAND operator are:

```
X + Y = x' NAND y' ??
X * Y = 
X' = X NAND 1
```

The equations for AND, OR and NOT using only the NOR operator are:

```
X' = ?
X + Y = (X NOR Y) NOR 0
X * Y = X' NOR Y' ??
```

I am trying to follow this formula

```
An OR gate with a NOT in both inputs is equivalent to a NAND.
An AND gate with a NOT in both inputs is equivalent to a NOR.
An OR gate with a NOT in its output is equivalent to a NOR.
An AND gate with a NOT in its output is equivalent to a NAND.
```

this is how i worked out AND to NOR equivalent

```
X  Y    X AND Y      X NOR Y    
-----------------------------
0  0       0            1
0  1       0            0
1  0       0            0
1  1       1            0

X'  Y'   X' NOR Y'
-------------------
1   1        0
1   0        0
0   1        0
0   0        1
```

My biggest problem is how do i use a NOT in the outputs in a truth table? Also, how would i go from a NOT to a NOR? I want to work all these out in a truth table.

```
X * Y = "An AND gate with a NOT in its output is equivalent to a NAND."
```

what are the outputs in a  truth table? and how can i go from a X' to equivalent NAND?

Comment: Read up on de Morgan's laws: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that,

```
X   X'
------
0   1
1   0
```

Hence,

```
X   X NOR X
------------
0      1
1      0
```

So we get,

```
X' = X NOR X
```

For your second question, suppose you have two inputs `X'` & `Y'` and you want to get to `X NAND Y`,

`X NAND Y = (X AND Y)' = X' OR Y'` (by [DeMorgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws))

Hence, the truth tables are as follows:

```
X  Y    X AND Y     (X AND Y)'    
-----------------------------
0  0       0            1
0  1       0            1
1  0       0            1
1  1       1            0

X  Y    X'   Y'      X' OR Y'    
-----------------------------
0  0    1    1          1
0  1    1    0          1
1  0    0    1          1
1  1    0    0          0
```

Answer (score 1):

> how do i use a NOT in the outputs in
>   a truth table

Put a bar over the column label, if you want to indicate reverse-polarity on the output.

> Also, how would i go from a NOT to a
>   NOR

Tie the two inputs of the NOR together.  That makes it the equivalent of a NOT.

Comment: Can you give me an example? "how do i use a NOT in the outputs in a truth table" because if you look at my example of "how i worked out AND to NOR equivalent" you will see theres no room fora NOT? Or, is my output answer in wrong form?